# Show All Button - JSX Logic

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I'm trying to develop a button that once I click it I show all the items available on my shopping list. But I'm struggling to put all the pieces together and come up with the correct syntax.

I have an array with 20 items and I would like to have initially only 15 (I'm assuming I'd have to use useState there?) displayed on the screen. Once I'd click the button it would show all the items on my shopping list array. Can any body help me to structure this feature? Thanks :)

```
const showAll = useCallback(() => {
    const availableItems = items;

    if (availableItems > 15) {
      //STRUGGLING
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="items.container">
      <ul className="shoplist-items">
        {items.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <li className="items">
              <div className="single-item" key={i}>
                {item}
              </div>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      <div className="show-all-container">
        <p onClick={showAll}>Show all</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use useState hook from react, init your avaible items only with 15 elements to show, and map avaibleItems instead items, and onClick just set avaibleItems:

```
const [avaibleItems, setAvaibleItems] = useState(items.slice(0,15); 
const showAll = () =>{ setAvaibleItems(items)}
```

Comment: I like the simplicity in your solution but don't you get an error if items is less than 15 items? Also you are missing an parethesis. Maybe like this:

const [avaibleItems, setAvaibleItems] = useState(items.length > 15 ? items.slice(0,15) : items);

Answer (score 1):

```
const allItems = useRef(items);
const [visibleItems, setVisibleItems] = useState(allItems.current.slice(0,15));


const showAll = useCallback(() => {
    if(allItems.current.length > 15) {
      setVisibleItems(allItems.current);
    }
}

  return (
    <div className="items.container">
      <ul className="shoplist-items">
        {visibleItems.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <li className="items">
              <div className="single-item" key={i}>
                {item}
              </div>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      <div className="show-all-container">
        <p onClick={showAll}>Show all</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: This is amazing and works perfectly! Thank you very, very much!